# How to filter value based on specific word in BI Publisher using RTF

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

how can I filter attribute output based on word. for example

`<?Store_Location?>` --> I just want to show stores in NY

tried `<?if:Store_location Contains ('NY')?>` but its not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
<?if:contains(Store_location,'NY')?>
```

**Example XML**

```
<record_set>
<record>
<rownum>1</rownum>
<transaction_id>111</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>2</rownum>
<transaction_id>222</transaction_id>
<amount>300</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>3</rownum>
<transaction_id>333</transaction_id>
<amount>430</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>4</rownum>
<transaction_id>444</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
</record_set>
```

**Example RTF**

```
<?for-each:record_set?>
<?for-each:record?>
<?if:contains(amount,'3')?>
Transaction ID: <?transaction_id?>
Amount:<?amount?>
<?end if?>
<?end for each?> 
<?end for each?>
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, its giving me the following error       oracle.xdo.XDOException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parse Error in Contains function.
oracle.xdo11g.xpath.XPathException: Parse Error in Contains function.
 at oracle.xdo.template.fo.util.FOUtility.generateFO(FOUtility.java:1300)
 at oracle.xdo.template.fo.util.FOUtility.generateFO(FOUtility.java:308)
 at oracle.xdo.template.FOProcessor.createFO(FOProcessor.java:2110)
 at oracle.xdo.template.FOProcessor.generate(FOProcessor.java:1213)
 at RTF2PDF2.runRTFto(RTF2PDF2.java:484)

Comment: Can you show the actual text of the RTF details you are having problems with. Please use Copy and Paste to make sure you are showing exactly what is causing the error. I just tried a smart quote, that was my first hunch, but seems BI Publisher desktop is allowing for those. Also, where are you testing this? Can you share the files you are using?

Comment: Hi Ed, I am using the BIPublisher add on in word. here is the code 
<?if: Contains(DOCUMENT_NAME, ('Year'))?>
<?DOCUMENT_NAME?>
<?end if?>

Comment: Remove the extra spaces, and parenthesis. Also, the function is case sensitive. Make sure it's all lower case. use: <?if:contains(DOCUMENT_NAME,'Year')?>

Comment: Thanks EdHayes3, much appreciated. its working now. do you have any link or documents you can share on the basics ? its definitely a new skill set for me which I am learning one at a time

Comment: You can find the BI Publisher Report Designers Guid and BI Publisher Administrator Guide on Oracle's website. Lots of times you just have to search google/bing and it will find some Oracle blog entry from years ago. Nice that documentation is in their blog entries...